# Factory function gives "Error: is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Im having trouble making a http.get call to my api. Here is the setup:

**user.js**

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
   function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/hem');

     $stateProvider.state('anvandare', {
       url: '/anvandare',
       views: {
         'main': {
           controller: 'UserController',
           templateUrl: 'modules/user/user.tpl.html'
         }
       }
     });

}])

.controller('UserController', 
  ['$scope', '$http', 'userFactory', function($scope, $http, userFactory) {
    this.users = [{name: "Patrik"}];
    $scope.message = userFactory.test();

    userFactory.getUsers().then(function(users) {
      $scope.users = users;
    });
}])

.factory('userFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

   return {
     test: function() {
       return "hello world";
     },
     getUsers: function() {
       $http.get('/api/user');
     }
   };
 }]);
```

**modules/user/user.tpl.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="UserController as UserCtrl">
  <h1>Users</h1>

  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So right now, I have cache disabled and Im seeing no 304:s on the request so I know all the responses are fresh, and I can see the `<h1>Users</h1> <p>{{message}}</p>` and message is = "hello world" as it should, but the list of users is not showing up. As I look i chrome tools on the page it says

```
"Error: userFactory.getUsers(...) is undefined"
```

When type 'localhost:5000/api/user' in my browser I do get all users back in json

```
[{"_id":"54e4c44f8d18e2a43f58935f","name":"Patrik","__v":0,"updated_at":"2015-02-18T16:56:47.105Z"},{"_id":"54e4c4588d18e2a43f589360","name":"Patrik Nygren","__v":0,"updated_at":"2015-02-18T16:56:56.603Z"},{"_id":"54e4c45f8d18e2a43f589361","name":"Patrik Ackerfors","__v":0,"updated_at":"2015-02-18T16:57:03.011Z"},{"_id":"54e4c4888d18e2a43f589362","__v":0,"updated_at":"2015-02-18T16:57:44.226Z"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `getUsers` function. You need to `return $http.get('/api/user');`

Comment: Yes, that was it, make a answer and Ill resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Tbh that isn't going to help anyone else...probably ever :) You should just delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must return something from your `getUsers` method:

```
 getUsers: function() {
   return $http.get('/api/user');
 }
```